# ¿Cómo leer el contenido de un archivo, obteniendo su contenido como String en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actualmente para poder leer un archivo y guardar su contenido como String utilizo la siguiente forma:

```
   System.IO.StreamReader archivo = new System.IO.StreamReader(destinationFile);
                        String archivoTXT_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                        archivoXML.Close();
```

Pero lo que yo deseo, es obtener el contenido de un archivo que está adjuntado en un correo de forma directa, pero hasta ahora no he podido, lo unico que he podido hacer para guardar el contenido del archivo en String, es guardar el archivo que leo de correo en un carpeta y despues guardado, leer su contenido para guardarlo en una variable String. Lo que yo deseo, es evitar este paso demas, el de tener que guardar el adjunto para almacenar en una variable string su contenido. La forma como lo hago es la siguiente:

```
 IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = Client.GetMessages(uids, FetchOptions.Normal);
 foreach (MailMessage msg in messages)
    foreach (Attachment atc in msg.Attachments)
                {
                        byte[] allBytes = new byte[msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length];
                        int bytesRead = msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length);
                        String digitosAleatorio = GetNumeroAleatorio();

                        string destinationFile = Server.MapPath("Adjuntos/" + digitosAleatorio + msg.Attachments[0].Name);
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
                        writer.Write(allBytes);
                        writer.Close();

                        System.IO.StreamReader archivoXML = new System.IO.StreamReader(destinationFile);
                        String archivoTXT_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                        archivoXML.Close();
         }
 }
```

Deseo poder almacenar directamente en la variable archivoTXT_texto el el adjunto, y no hacer otro paso demás, el de guardarlo en una carpeta.Es decir, tratar de hacer algo como:

```
System.IO.StreamReader archivoXML = new    System.IO.StreamReader(msg.Attachments[0]);
String archivoTXT_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                        archivoXML.Close();
```

sin tener la necesidad de hacer este paso:

```
  string destinationFile = Server.MapPath("AdjuntosXML/" + digitosAleatorio + msg.Attachments[0].Name);
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
                        writer.Write(allBytes);
                        writer.Close();
```

Espero poder tener la solución. Saludos.

Nota: Uso el protocolo IMAP para leer correos

Comment: Utiliza un `MemoryStream` en lugar de un `FileStream`. De esa manera los datos les tendras en memoria en lugar de pasar por un archivo intermedio.

Comment: Y no se podría hacer alguna conversion directa de los contenidos de los archivos que es texto en string??